# Using bind variables in stored procedure PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in Oracle using the following statements:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPD_INBOX 
    (tbl_inbox in VARCHAR2, tbl_rjc OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS    
    CURSOR c1 IS
         select I.ROWID_IN, R.DESC || '-' || J.TIPO || ';' RECHAZO_DESC
           from DV.INBOX I, DV.REJECT R, DV.TIPO_RECHAZO J 
           where I.rowid_in = R.rowid_in
           and R.TIPO_R=J.TIPO_R;
       cRec c1%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
         UPDATE DV.INBOX set zError=0,zErrorDescription='';
         commit;
         OPEN c1;
         LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO cRec;
            EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
            UPDATE DV.INBOX SET ERROR=ERROR+1, Error_Desc=Error_Desc || cRec.REJTXT WHERE ROWID_IN=cRec.ROWID_IN;
         END LOOP;
       COMMIT;
      CLOSE c1;
END;
```

But I have an error when compiling:

`:tbl_inbox` and `:tbl_rcj` aren't recognized as valid tables and have the error "PL 00049 Bad bind variables". Is it possible to do that properly?

I tried substituting FROM clause for:

```
from :tbl_inbox I, :tbl_reject R, DV.TIPO_RECHAZO J
```

But have the error:

```
Error(7,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Edit: I post my entire code and works well. I'm just trying to set as parameter the name of tables that I was going to use each call to procedure. They aren't going to be the same.

Comment: You don't need the colons, you're referring to formal arguments, not independent bind variables. But you can use variables for object names in static SQL. You have to use dynamic SQL. There are lots of examples around. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27592366/266304).

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I'm trying to create parameters because this procedure is going to be called a lot of times from ETL processes and need to be uselful in that way.

Comment: Why are you using `tbl_rjc` as a part of the cursor's select, if it is defined as an `OUT` parameter? Also, to use table names dynamically, it is better to tell us what do you exactly want to do from the `CURSOR` in the further steps. A dynamic cursor may not be used the way you are trying to use: (`cRec c1%ROWTYPE;`)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23060374/266304) might be more useful as you're replacing a cursor. But for ETL you might want [a single insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51929562/266304) instead.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Why are you referring to an OUT parameter in the FROM clause? I suggest you get your code working with **fixed** table names first; once you have done that you can convert it into dynamic SQL using parameterized names.

Comment: What is the purpose of input parameters `tbl_inbox` and `tbl_rcj`? They are not used in your code.

Comment: I'm trying to use them into FROM clause (from DV.INBOX I, DV.REJECT R) substituting DV.INBOX and DV.REJECT each time procedure is called. But I have the error Error(7,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Comment: They were in the original code you posted; maybe add the attempt to change that code to use the parameters. (OK, you just did, sort of; but with colons you'd get a bind error, and to get the error you show you've removed the colons, right?) But as already said, you need to use dynamic SQL to supply the table name at run-time, and it doesn't make sense for `tbl_rjc` to be `n OUT parameter.

Comment: Also, your updates will have to be dynamic too. You probably want a single dynamic correlated update, instead of the row-by-row updates inside a dynamic loop.